# List Members based on extended profile fields in buddypress

Tags: buddypress

I'm working on getting a list of members based on the fields they selected on the extended profiles fields in buddypress. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$membership_group = "Orange Membership";
$db_query = "SELECT user_id FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE field_id = 33 AND value = \"" .$membership_group ."\""; 
$match_ids = $wpdb->get_var($db_query);
$get_these_members = 'include=' .$match_ids;

if (bp_has_members($get_these_members, 'per_page optional=9')) {
    //Some Codes here
} 
?>
```

The result is returning just the first member it gets from the query instead of a list of members. Please say what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should dive into the class `BP_Core_User` and its method `get_users`. It supports meta_key and meta_value.
You can also try to make just a search by field value. So pass an argument `s` to `bp_has_members`.

And `per_page optional=9` is a wrong syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This:
$wpdb->get_var($db_query);

returns a single var !

This is what you want:
$wpdb->get_col($db_query);

Then fix the syntax error mentioned by slaFFik